# converting array into appropriate json format in yii1

Tags: php, json, yii

I am using Yii1. I have following code which converts array into json:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
/*      $this->layout='//layouts/datatable';*/
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
            $model = Company::model()->findAll();
            $data = array_map(function ($model) {
                return $model->attributes;
            }, $model);
            $responce = json_encode($data);
            var_dump($responce);
            return $responce;
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('list');
        }
    }
```

It returns json data `string(1221) "[{"c_id":"1","c_name":"Marokand", ...`
However, i need json data with the following format:

```
[{c_id: 1, c_name: "Marokand",...
```

Comment: Why you need to strip out the quotation marks? The result you are actually getting is valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo` instead of `var_dump()`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of return, i used echo. It gave me expected result.

Comment: that is what Arya answered, you should accept her answer instead of posting your own one with the same content.